# Spring MVC: How to allow null values in top-level field in Dozer through API?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mapping, dozer

I am using Dozer to map between entities and DTO's and I want to allow an null value of Date type in top-level field of my DTO.

Exclusion of field works fine, but this is not satisfactory solution because then it is always mapped to null:

```
mapping(InspectionInterval.class, InspectionIntervalDTO.class)
    .exclude("lastPerformedOn");
```

I would like to do something like:

```
mapping(InspectionInterval.class, InspectionIntervalDTO.class)
    .fields("lastPerformedOn", "lastPerformedOn", FieldsMappingOptions.allowNull());
```

In the documentation, there is just example how to do it using XML configuration, but I am not able to figure out how to do it using API: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/advancedConfiguration.html

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: So by "allow null" you mean "don't overwrite an existing value if the DTO value is null"?

Comment: No, null (no Date set) is a valid value in this case. But Dozer throws NullPointerException if it is not set.

Comment: Then be more specific about the issue. You did not describe that behavior.

Comment: I wanted to achieve the same behavior using an API (Java code) configuration as in XML configuration, which is described in referenced documentation page http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/advancedConfiguration.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by switching to XML configuration.